# Using shaders and svg in p5js

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I know that if I want to use shaders in p5js I need to use WEBGL mode, and that if I want to export SVG, I need to work with p5js-svg (https://github.com/zenozeng/p5.js-svg) but how can I do both at the same time?

If I do

```
createCanvas(width, height, SVG);
```

shaders are not working, and if I do

```
createCanvas(width, height, WEBGL);
```

SVG is not working. Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can't, you can either use the SVG backend or the WebGL backend.
There's libraries that allow you to convert SVG into buffers that WebGL understands, however I'm not sure if there's p5 integrations for those.